# AngularJS - is there any dependency injection container?

Tags: angularjs

Have a look into my AngularJS controller:

```
MyApp.controller('MyAppController', function($scope, $http, $filter, 
                                             $location, $window, FileUploader) {
    // ...
});
```

Is there any Dependency Injection Container or current approach looks fine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks fine, but if you plan on minifying your code later on you will need to write the code like this instead so that Angular knows what to inject:

```
MyApp.controller('MyAppController', ['$scope', '$http', '$filter', '$location', '$window', 'FileUploader', function($scope, $http, $filter, $location, $window, FileUploader) {

 ...

}]);
```

If you use [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/), there is a plugin [ng-annotate](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate) which I've found very useful and it takes care of this extra code for you. Saves you from having to write everything twice.

Answer (score 3):

Angularjs takes care of the dependency injection for you, but to put the dependencies in an array like below, explicitly states what should be injected.  If the parameters in the function are minified to 'a', or 'b', the array let's angularjs know what to inject.

```
MyApp.controller('MyAppController', ['$scope', '$http', '$filter', '$location', '$window', 'FileUploader', function($scope, $http, $filter, $location, $window, FileUploader) {

 ...

}])
```